# Unable to mount NFS version 3

Tags: linux, nfs

I am trying to mount an NFS share specifically with NFS version 3. I have two clusters of servers, on one it works and the other it does not. Where it does work I have

`10.100.30.81:/var/lib/test /var/lib/test nfs hard,bg,intr,vers=3,noatime 0 0`

and it works fine. If I use `rpcinfo` I get this

```
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100005    1   udp  20048  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  20048  mountd
    100005    2   udp  20048  mountd
    100024    1   udp  43989  status
    100005    2   tcp  20048  mountd
    100024    1   tcp  44845  status
    100005    3   udp  20048  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  20048  mountd
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    3   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
    100227    3   udp   2049  nfs_acl
    100021    1   udp  56714  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  56714  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  56714  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  44307  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  44307  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  44307  nlockmgr
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
[root@test1 ~]#
```

On the system that does not work I have set up

```
10.200.100.80:/var/lib/test2 /var/lib/test2 nfs soft,bg,intr,vers=3,noatime 0 0
```

When I try to mount it I get

```
[root@mon2 ~]# mount -avvvvvvvv
/                        : ignored
/boot                    : already mounted
swap                     : ignored
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'soft,bg,intr,vers=3,addr=10.200.100.80'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Program not registered
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Program not registered
mount.nfs: backgrounding "10.200.100.80:/var/lib/test2"
mount.nfs: mount options: "rw,noatime,soft,bg,intr,vers=3"
/var/lib/test2        : successfully mounted
[root@mon2 ~]
```

If I run `rpcinfo` I get back

```
[root@mon2 ~]# rpcinfo -p  10.200.100.80
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
[root@mon2 ~]#
```

I assume my issues that I have something reconfigured on my NFS server? I checked and `rpcbind` and other services seem to be running the same on both. What else can I loo at?

Answer (score 2):

```
[root@mon2 ~]# rpcinfo -p  10.200.100.80
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
```

According to the `portmapper` service, there are no `nfs`, `nfs_acl`, `status`, `mountd` nor `nlockmgr` services running on 10.200.100.80. A NFSv3 server should be running all of those, and the system's `portmapper` service should know about them.

The `mount` command calls other `/sbin/mount.<filesystem type>` utilities if it cannot handle that specific filesystem type internally. For NFS, there is a specific utility `/sbin/mount.nfs` which will handle NFS mounts.

When mounting a NFSv3 share, one of the first things the `mount.nfs` utility does is asking the `portmapper` service of the NFS server system about the protocols available and the ports to use with them.

```
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
```

This is the `mount.nfs` utility asking the NFS server's `portmapper` service: "Do you have the `nfs` service version 3 on TCP?" (you can check the prog and prot numbers from `/etc/rpc` and `/etc/protocols` files, respectively)

```
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Program not registered
```

And the server responds with "Sorry, I don't have that service."

```
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=17
```

"Well do you have NFS version 3 on UDP, then?"

```
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Program not registered
```

"Sorry, I don't have that either."

```
mount.nfs: backgrounding "10.200.100.80:/var/lib/test2"
```

Here, because the `bg` mount option was used, the `mount.nfs` sets up a background process to keep retrying the NFS mount, in case the server will start its NFS services at some later time. Since it will keep retrying, `mount.nfs` cannot really tell the main `mount` command that it failed, because the mount operation might succeed later, so `mount.nfs` will return a "success" result code to the main `mount` command.

```
/var/lib/test2        : successfully mounted
```

The ,som `mount` command does not have a clue about the details of the NFS mounting process, so it assumes the "success" result code means the filesystem was successfully mounted. In this specific case, the result code just means the `mount.nfs` has not stopped trying yet.

---

So the problem is clearly on host 10.200.100.80: according to its `portmapper`, it is not running the services necessary to act as a NFS server.

Too bad you did not specify the name and version of the operating system used on that host: the steps to start up the NFS server services vary somewhat between Linux distributions.

Even if the NFS server services have been configured to start automatically, some distributions will check the contents of `/etc/exports`: if no NFS shares are configured there, the start-up scripts might omit starting the NFS server services. So you should first check that the host 10.200.100.80's `/etc/exports` file defines `/var/lib/test2` as a NFSv3 share, and then figure out how to start the NFS server services on that host (and also how to configure them to start automatically at boot in the future).

Typically, the services `nfs`, `nfs_acl` and `nlockmgr` are handled by a in-kernel server, so a `/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd` will only run once to configure the kernel components and exit afterwards. The `status` and `mountd` services are handled by user-space processes running `/usr/sbin/rpc.statd` and `/usr/sbin/rpc.mountd`, respectively. There might be a single script, `systemd` service or target that starts all of these, or you might have to start them individually, depending on your Linux distribution.

On Debian/Ubuntu, `systemctl start nfs-server.service` could be the command you're looking for. On RHEL 7.x, there are two services: `nfs-lock` and `nfs`, that will both need to be started for NFSv3 server support.

Comment: If nfs is not started then how come I can mount NFS v4?

Comment: Oh, then the problem might be that someone has stopped `rpcbind` and restarted it incorrectly, so it has failed to save/restore any previous service registrations and now believes there are no other RPC services running, while that's not necessarily true. NFSv4 got rid of the extra services in other ports and only uses port 2049, to the great relief of everyone dealing with firewalls... and so v4 won't really need `rpcbind` either.

Comment: A restart of rpcbind did not fix it. A restart of nfs-server did.